# Selenium finding button on discord website

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[Screenshot of Website with inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkhPS.png)

I am trying to press the "Integrations" button by using

```
int = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "side-8zPYf6")))
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(int).perform()
```

But it is not working.

Below is the html of this panel:

```html
<div class="sidebarRegionScroller-3MXcoP thin-1ybCId scrollerBase-289Jih fade-2kXiP2" dir="ltr" style="overflow: hidden scroll; padding-right: 0px;">
   <nav class="sidebar-CFHs9e">
      <div class="side-8zPYf6" role="tabbar" aria-orientation="vertical">
         <div class="header-2RyJ0Y" tabindex="-1" role="button"> </div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="OVERVIEW-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Overview</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ROLES-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Roles</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="EMOJI-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Emoji</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="MODERATION-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Moderation</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="AUDIT_LOG-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Audit Log</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ selected-3s45Ha themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="INTEGRATIONS-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Integrations">Integrations</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="WIDGET-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Widget</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="GUILD_TEMPLATES-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Server Template">Server Template</div>
         <div class="separator-gCa7yv"></div>
         <div class="header-2RyJ0Y" tabindex="-1" role="button">Community</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="COMMUNITY-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Overview">Overview</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ANALYTICS-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Server Insights">Server Insights</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="PARTNER-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Partner Program">Partner Program</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="DISCOVERY-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Enable Discovery">Discovery</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="MEMBER_VERIFICATION-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Membership Screening</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="COMMUNITY_WELCOME-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Welcome Screen">Welcome Screen</div>
         <div class="separator-gCa7yv"></div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="GUILD_PREMIUM-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" style="color: rgb(114, 137, 218);">Server Boost Status</div>
         <div class="separator-gCa7yv"></div>
         <div class="header-2RyJ0Y" tabindex="-1" role="button">User Management</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="MEMBERS-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Members</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="INSTANT_INVITES-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Invites</div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="BANS-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1">Bans</div>
         <div class="separator-gCa7yv"></div>
         <div class="item-PXvHYJ themed-OHr7kt" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="DELETE-tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" style="color: rgb(240, 71, 71);">Delete Server</div>
      </div>
   </nav>
   <div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; pointer-events: none; min-height: 0px; min-width: 1px; flex: 0 0 auto; height: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see there are class names.
Use it if it's really unique.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item-PXvHYJ.themed-OHr7kt")))
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".item-PXvHYJ.themed-OHr7kt")
button.click()
```

`.` is placed before class name.

**Update:**
Add wait time for this button.

**Update 2**:
As the above locator appeared to be not unique,
Use this css:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-controls='INTEGRATIONS-tab']")
```

Comment: Possibly dynamic class names... Need to see the web page to locate the element correctly

Comment: Probably you are right. However, I think they would be dynamic for sure if they has some numbers in the end like,` item-PXvHYJ123`

Comment: I wrote 

`create_webhook = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".item-PXvHYJ.themed-OHr7kt")
create_webhook.click()
`
Still not working

Comment: Is there another way to click the button, i have been trying for hours.....

Comment: I'll suggest one. But you are asking a different question in comments. Next time please post your code and the problem you face

Comment: I meant i tried doing what u told i think, and its still not working, nothing is being clicked,

i replaced 

`int = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "side-8zPYf6")))
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(int).perform() `
 
with 

`int = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".item-PXvHYJ.themed-OHr7kt")
int.click()`

Comment: Check that class names are ok

Comment: btw all of the buttons on the left has the same class name

Comment: Add html code. No sense to answer it anymore

Comment: With code inspector take the whole panel html code and paste it to any onlne html formatter. Then post here

Comment: Like this ? 
`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".div[aria-controls='INTEGRATIONS-tab']")))
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".div[aria-controls='INTEGRATIONS-tab']")
button.click()`

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-controls='INTEGRATIONS-tab']"))) button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-controls='INTEGRATIONS-tab']") button.click()

Comment: It is unable to locate element

Comment: i wrote 
`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) 
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-controls='INTEGRATIONS-tab']"))) 
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-controls='INTEGRATIONS-tab']") 
button.click()`

Comment: Which error do you see? Integrations locator is unique now

Comment: oh wait, it worked after i restarted, Thanks alot for the help!!